# python DNS server_client malformed packets

Tags: python, networking, network-programming

i have a problem where i get malformed packets in the wireshark while i run my DNS server and client that i made, im unable to know what the problem is, the idea of the DNS server is to sniff packets that are sent through DNS protocol and extract the information of it and send a response to the client, this is my DNS server:

```
import socket

# Server parameters
server_ip = '127.0.0.1'
server_port = 53

# Create a UDP socket for DNS communication
dns_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
dns_socket.bind((server_ip, server_port))
print(f"DNS server listening on {server_ip}:{server_port}")

# Loop to handle incoming DNS requests
while True:
    # Receive a DNS query from a client
    dns_query, client_address = dns_socket.recvfrom(1024)
    try:
        query_str = dns_query.decode('utf-8')
        print(f"Received DNS query '{query_str}' from {client_address[0]}:{client_address[1]}")
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        print(f"Received DNS query from {client_address[0]}:{client_address[1]}")

    # Resolve the DNS query and get the corresponding IP address
    # This is where you would implement your own DNS resolution logic
    ip_address = '10.9.1.205'

    # Send the IP address back to the client as the DNS response
    dns_socket.sendto(ip_address.encode(), client_address)
    print(f"Sent DNS response '{ip_address}' to {client_address[0]}:{client_address[1]}")
```

this is my client:

```
import socket

# Client parameters
server_ip = '127.0.0.1'
server_port = 53
query_domain = 'www.google.com'

# Create a UDP socket for DNS communication
dns_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
dns_socket.bind((server_ip, 0))  # Use any available port for client

# Construct the DNS query message
# See https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/dns-records/dns-message-format/
# for the format of a DNS query message
dns_query = b'\xab\xcd'  # 2-byte transaction ID
dns_query += b'\x01\x00'  # Standard query with recursion
dns_query += b'\x00\x01'  # One question in the query
dns_query += b'\x00\x00'  # No answers, authority, or additional sections
dns_query += b'\x00\x00'  # No answers, authority, or additional sections
dns_query += bytes.fromhex('03 77 77 77')  # www
dns_query += bytes.fromhex('06 67 6f 6f 67 6c 65')  # google
dns_query += bytes.fromhex('03 63 6f 6d')  # com
dns_query += b'\x00'  # End of domain name
dns_query += b'\x00\x01'  # Type A (IPv4 address) query
dns_query += b'\x00\x01'  # Class IN (Internet)

# Send the DNS query to the DNS server
dns_socket.sendto(dns_query, (server_ip, server_port))
print(f"Sent DNS query '{query_domain}' to {server_ip}:{server_port}")

# Wait for the DNS response from the server
dns_response, server_address = dns_socket.recvfrom(1024)
print(f"Received DNS response '{dns_response.decode()}' from {server_address[0]}:{server_address[1]}")

# Close the socket
dns_socket.close()
```

*note* i have tried several clients it is still malformed packets, in the pycharm i get information but in the wireshark as i mentioned are malformed packet, i would like to know the reason behind that and how to fix it, i am getting this problem aswell in the dhcp server with another server.

Comment: DNS is a complicated protocol, you cannot simply send an ip address encoded as a string. You can read up on the protocol on Wikipedia or RFC 1035, here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035

Comment: I would recommend using a library for implementing a custom DNS, as someone who has tried a similar project before.

Comment: i have to do evey thing manually o using scapy is also possible

Comment: In that case you will have to do some research into the protocol, are you doing this for a school assignment or something? I may be able to continue to help if you have more questions, but you will have to first figure out how the protocol works.

Comment: yes its kind of a project ihave to do, i have just upgraded it now and iwould like some hlep yes

Comment: Like I said, you will need to do some reading yourself. However, if you read https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035, specifically 4.1.1 and 4.1.2, you will have a better understanding of the format. Once you have implemented this, and have more questions or issues, you can let me know.

Comment: Correction: All under 4.1 would be necessary reading for a fully implemented DNS.

Comment: You forgot the ```ARCOUNT``` field. The size of the DNS message header is 12 not 10.